# Tools to analyze code syntax

Tags: java, string, design-patterns

I want to go through all available Java (or any other language) source code in a given project and:

1. set up a statistical distribution of permutations of keywords and their relations
2. pick out repetitive sequences characters, constructions (patterns) out of it.

**What kind of toolset would you recommend me?**

For example:

I want it to be able to pick:

```
* ( * ) {
  *
}
```

out of

```
public static void main ( String[] args ) {
  System.err.println( "Specific Text" );
}
```

or

```
\n;
```

out of

```
  System.err.println( "Specific Text" );
  System.err.println( "Specific Text" );
  System.err.println( "Specific Text" );
  System.err.println( "Specific Text" );
  System.err.println( "Specific Text" );
  System.err.println( "Specific Text" );
  System.err.println( "Specific Text" );
  System.err.println( "Specific Text" );
```

Comment: ctrl+F in your IDE with regex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a language parser. One I can think of right is http://www.antlr.org/. You end up using grammar that already exists for Java and parse a file and look for tokens. For example, if,for,when,etc... are all keywords that the parser will tell you. But 123 is not a keyword.

Comment: BTW, Terence Parr ( ANTLR author ) wrote this book: http://pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns  which explains easily how to do a "language app" like the one you need. If you don't know anything about tokenizers, parsers, ast's and etc. I recommend you to read this boook.